# Jenkins: Refresh jobs readed from the FileSystem

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cloudbees

I am using CloudBees Folder plugin, so I am able to create folders, but imagine this folders structure for the jobs:

```
/
  /production
  /test
```

And I have one job '**dummyjob**' in 'test' folder, for example:

```
/
  /production
  /test/dummyjob
```

When I want to recreate the '**dummyjob**' in production folder I am not able to create a new job in 'production' folder with option:

**'Copy Existing Item'**

Because It cannot read from '**test**' folder what jobs are there.

So what I am doing in this moment it is to copy a paste the jobs in the File System, the annoying part is that i have to restart jenkins to take the changes in the Web Console.

What I have to do to avoid to restart jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

If it helps to someone, I did it in this way:

```
http://ip_jenkins:port_jenkins/jenkins/reload
```

It is faster than restart (obvious) and safe.

Tested in Jenkins 1.620

Answer (score 0):

Did you try typing in `test/dummyjob` in the origin job field? It [ought to work](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/jenkins-1.620/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/ItemGroupMixIn.java#L165-L170).

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, if you are a CloudBees customer running CloudBees Jenkins Operations Center, you can use the [Move/Copy/Promote](http://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cjoc-user-guide/move-copy-promote.html) feature, designed for this use case.